Use custom directory for Maven build cache extension (ideally per maven run)
Is there a way to modify the directory under which the maven build cache artifacts are stored locally when no remote server is used per execution, so ideally from the command line when running maven?
By default it is stored under ~/.m2/build-cache - is there any way to change that with a command line parameter when running maven?

Just check this: https://maven.apache.org/extensions/maven-build-cache-extension/build-cache-config.html#class_local

@khmarbaise thanks, good to know, ideal would be something that can be set on the command line though, I'll make the question more specific

ah, with the default lcoation config it works indirectly by setting the local m2/repository path as the build cache is relative to it by default; so as long as one is fine with also moving the artifact repository then the build cache basically follows.
@khmarbaise Feel free to make this into an answer.

Turns out, you cannot specifically set the build cache directory via the command line. However, the default location is defined relative to the regular maven repository directory. So if you change the repository directory to ~/custom-maven-dir/repository via
-Dmaven.repo.local=~/custom-maven-dir/repository/ then the build cache directory will be at ~/custom-maven-dir/build-cache
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise for pointing me to the documentation that had the information about the relative default path for the build cache.
Note that you can set a fixed path for the build cache in the build cache extension config file (see https://maven.apache.org/extensions/maven-build-cache-extension/build-cache-config.html#class_local )
However, that is then a static setting for the project not a command line option.
